# What is the origin of the phrase "you've got another thing/think coming"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, grammar, idioms, nouns

What is the origin of the phrase "you've got another thing coming"? And — perhaps more importantly — is it more correct than the alternative "you've got another think coming"?

Comment: I think I'll have another think about this one. :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the phrase was older than I expected. [NGrams reports](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=got+another+thing+coming%2Chave+another+thing+coming&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) the following matches for the phrases "got another thing coming" and "have another thing coming":

[NGram image http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=got%20another%20thing%20coming%2Chave%20another%20thing%20coming&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1880&year_end=2000](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=got%20another%20thing%20coming%2Chave%20another%20thing%20coming&corpus=0&smoothing=3&year_start=1880&year_end=2000)

Here is quote from [1906](http://books.google.com/books?id=LAYNAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA214&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U2ppQbnx9Uxe5mmOFTEkwo_fd6gbg&ci=155%2C368%2C759%2C88&edge=0) (I think. I am still learning how Google Books works.):

> But if we did, then we have another thing coming, for this is 
>   the cry-baby talk I find in this morning's (Dec. 16) editorial

As for your other question, "you've got another think coming" wasn't an established idiom as far as I was aware, but the [NGrams results](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=got+another+think+coming%2Cgot+another+thing+coming&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shocked me:

[image: NGrams results]

The usage and meaning seem identical to "thing" but I find it odd that I don't recall ever seeing it in print. Looking to [phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/another-think-coming.html):

> 'Another thing coming' is just a mispronunciation of the original phrase. The source of this mistake is probably the duplicated 'k' sounds of 'think' and 'coming'.

Most of the other sites I checked said similar things. Namely, "think" is the correct version and "thing" is the malformation. The origin appears to revolve around someone thinking one thing but an apparent correct will be coming shortly: They will need to rethink their previous thought (and ideally arrive at the correct position this time.)

Comment: Huh, whodathunk that?

Comment: "With what confusion thinking's fraught!/ I sometimes think I'll think no more./For when I spend much time in thought/ I unthink things I thought before."

Comment: Plotting all 4 combinations of have/got and thing/think together shows some interesting trends around the origin of the phrase.  The rise of the "think" variants coincides with the decline of the original spike of "have another thing coming".  http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=got+another+think+coming%2Cgot+another+thing+coming%2Chave+another+think+coming%2Chave+another+thing+coming&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: This answer is misleading. I've just checked Google Books entries for *"have another **thing** coming"* - the earliest one for the sense under discussion here is [this from 1970](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22classroom+you+have+another+thing%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). That's more than a century after the original (and far more common) **think** version was first recorded. That original is a well-established idiomatic usage; the new "variant" is both misguided and relatively uncommon.

Comment: FWIW... this answer includes "got another thing coming" in both charts -- that is, it only plots 3 versions, and omits "have another think coming" from both charts. Here's the link to plot all 4 phrases together, for quick comparison: (see subsequent comment, link too long)

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+another+thing+coming%2Chave+another+think+coming%2Cgot+another+thing+coming%2Cgot+another+think+coming&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20another%20thing%20coming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20another%20think%20coming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20another%20thing%20coming%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgot%20another%20think%20coming%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 9):

Before reading this question, I don't think I'd ever come across *"you've got another **thing** coming"*. I'm convinced by what Paul Brians says in [Common Errors in English Usage: The Book (2nd Edition, November, 2008)...](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/thing.html)

> The original expression is the last part of a deliberately ungrammatical joke: *“If that’s what you think, you’ve got another **think** coming.”*

Here's an instance from [*The Leather Workers' Journal, 1904*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BTCgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22another%20think%20coming%22&dq=%22another%20think%20coming%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_mrqwgp_eAhVRyqQKHS1aA0UQ6AEISjAI), showing it's been around a long time...

> *If the wage earner thinks that he will obtain anything from either of the old parties he has another think coming.*

---

EDIT: As noted in @Barrie's comment below, the noun usage of *a think* to mean *an **act** of thinking* is long-established (*"I'll have a think about that"* is perfectly normal). But note that this usage only really gained traction [in the past half-century.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20a%20think&year_start=1850&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20think%3B%2Cc0)

But in OP's context *a think* means ***what*** someone thinks, which is a non-standard usage. For example, we say *"My **thinking** is we should go"*, not *"My **think** is we should go"*. That's why as Paul Brians says in the above link, a few people in recent decades have tried to "correct" the deliberately quirky/non-standard original - but imho *they've got another **think** coming*.

Comment: The OED has a 1834 citation illustrating ‘think’ as a noun: ‘We lie lown yonder . . and have time for our ain think.’ There it means ‘An act of (continued or concerted) thinking.’  A year later, it’s first recorded as meaning ‘What someone thinks about a matter; a personal opinion’: ‘My own private think is that he will execute another voluntary.’

Comment: Punch is from [1953](https://books.google.co.uk/books?ei=TFq-T67eO4Gu8AP_5ull&id=KG8gAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22another+think+coming%22&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=1953).

Comment: @Laurel: Duly noted. As it turns out, that incorrectly-dated *Punch* cite was the only pre-1900 one I could find. But there are about a dozen written instances in the decade after 1900, so it was probably commonplace in spoken contexts before making it into print.

Answer (score 0):

"*Have/got another **thing** coming*" dates back to at least 1897:

> They imagine that these battles and quarrels of the track are carried on after the races are over. The people who think this ‘have another thing coming’, for the men travel in one of the most peaceful parties that follows any line of sport.
>   <sub>Elmira Daily Gazette & Free Press (New York)</sub>

According to the OED, it's "arising from misapprehension of *to have another **think** coming*". From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-another-think-coming-or-another-thing-coming) we know that this version dates back to at least 1867:

> "By Jove, Ned!" he exclaimed. "I believe I have it." "Have what—a fit of seasickness?" "No, but these empty seats—the persons we saw you know—they belong there and they're afraid to come out and be seen." "Why should they be—if they're not the Fogers. I guess you've got another think coming." "Well, I'm sure there's something mysterious about those two—the way they hid their faces as they came on board—not appearing at supper—I'm going to keep my eyes open."
>   — Jane G. Austin, Outpost, 1867

Answer (score -1):

I have never heard a learned person say another thing coming. The expression is a word play. If you think it's not you have another think coming. It makes perfect sense. If you say "If you think that you have another thing coming" what would it mean? What and where is this mysterious thing of which they speak? Many people think it's supposed to be "thing", but many more KNOW that think is the correct usage. Using thing is like some wannabe smart people that say "as best as I can" instead of "As best I can". They believe it makes them sound knowledgeable, but actually has the opposite effect.

Comment: Hi Kirk. "...another thing coming" is a well known idiom, so I'm not sure what your post is trying to convey. Do you have any evidence to support your post? You can [edit] your answer to provide information from authoritative sources. For further guidance, see [answer]. :-)

Comment: Regardless of whether it makes sense to you, or is familiar to you, it's definitely a common idiom. I grew up listening to this song on the radio, for instance: [Judas Priest - You've Got Another Thing Coming](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtuoFv4dcwM)