# Which is correct: "another think coming" or "another thing coming"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the origin of the phrase “you've got another thing/think coming”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24167/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-youve-got-another-thing-think-coming)

Which is correct: "another think coming" or "another thing coming"? I have seen/heard both. Is one correct or more common?

Comment: Interesting [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=another+thing+coming%2Canother+think+coming&year_start=1890&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) on this.  (That doesn't really answer the question per se, but it's a good starting place).

Answer (score 5):

The full phrase is *if you think x, you've got [another think coming](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_another_think_coming)*.

Wiktionary notes on usage:

> This expression is used as a rebuke, often in constructions similar to
>   "If X thinks that Y, he/she has another think coming!" Sometimes the
>   word got is included, in the familiar constructions has got and have
>   got, as "(someone)'s got another think coming", "they've/you've got
>   another think coming".
>
> **The form to have another thing coming is often seen, and may have been
>   aided by a mishearing of the /k/ of think blended with the /k/ of
>   coming, making think sound like thing.**

Comment: ...and thanks for the [Judas Priest](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U__m4N7Ml30&ob=av2n) [earworm](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/810/term-for-catchy-tune-that-stays-in-your-head).  :)

Comment: I'm so thankful for the earworm, that I could _kiss this guy_...

Comment: If you need to powder your nose, there's a bathroom on the right.

Answer (score 5):

In looking through the Ngram results (which heavily favor *think*), I stumbled across this very interesting excerpt from a book that addresses this very question:

> Other idioms in English are so opaque semantically that they have undergone phonological modifications possible only because speakers
>   could not even identify the component words.  While some speakers say,
>   "if you think X, you have another *thing* coming," other speakers
>   swear the correct form is "...you have another *think* coming," each
>   group doubting the very existence of the other dialect group until
>   confronted with a living member of it. (Nicolas Ruwet and John A. Goldsmith, *Syntax and Human Experience*)

Comment: Yeah, I grew up thinking it was _another thing coming_, and thinking no more about it. Until I encountered the _think_ spelling, and rethought it. Yes, that sort of makes sense. But it's still pronounced without a geminate /k/, so it doesn't matter how it's spelled; it'd be the same either way. Since then I haven't worried much about it.

Comment: Including the word _got_ in your Ngram will give much cleaner results. See @MrHen's answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/24172/5822).

Comment: I also grew up with *another thing* and I still don't believe *think* is original.  My thoughts are along the following lines.. Ehhmm,  Ready??  Lots of people, when laying out the list of arguments for their cause will follow that list with, "... And another thing... " and go on to list more arguments.  This was the origin of the phrase in my mind.  *Think*, I reasoned, was then just someone's clever pun.

Comment: @Jim: I'm not going to try to persuade you either way, but your adamance goes along nicely with what the authors of the book said, i.e., that many are often surprised to discover there is another camp.  (By the way, it never even occurred to me that it might be "another think coming" until I started researching this question. LSNED.)

Comment: @J.R. - Yes, after reading your answer I decided to phrase my reply here *adamantly* ;-)