# I had it coming

Tags: phrases, idioms

When you say "I had it coming", does it always mean "I caused it to happen to me"? Can it also mean in an appropriate context "it just happened to me"?

Also, does it always have to be "coming" and not base form "come" like "I had it come"?

Comment: It means *"I **deserved** it"* - where *"it"* is always something *bad*, and it's your own fault that it's happening to you.

Answer (score 5):

To *have something coming* is an idiom meaning that you deserved something. E.g.,

> My wife left me yesterday. **I had it coming** because I had an affair with her sister, and she found out about it.

Comment: Yes, but only when "you deserved it" means "it was your fault". You wouldn't normally say *"I got top marks in the exam. I had it coming because I'd been studying really hard all year"*.

Comment: I think it can be used both [positively](http://idioms.yourdictionary.com/have-it-coming) and negatively, but I agree that it **usually** has a strong negative connotation and means "I had some bad karma".

Comment: I think that "positive" example is "unusual", to say the least. Certainly it's a bad definition, since without any further explanatory text, one would naturally assume both possibilities are equally valid and likely to occur. In practice, native speakers would end up racking their brains trying to figure out why exactly winning the Nobel Prize might be considered "a bad thing".

Comment: I agree that it's unusual, but it's not surprising to me as an American speaker. People talk about actors & actresses who **finally** get the Oscar they deserve & have deserved for the last 10 years. My example sentence is much more typical of how the idiom's used & what it usually means.

Comment: 'Well, she's finally got an Oscar. She can't say she didn't have it coming to her.' I don't think so.

Comment: When you have _something_ coming, it means you deserved it, but when you have _another thing_ coming, well, I [think](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68801/which-is-correct-another-think-coming-or-another-thing-coming) that means something altogether different. 8^)

Comment: @Barrie: I don't think so either, but that's not how it's used. "Well, she's finally got an Oscar. She's had it coming for a long time" is more like it. However, "She's deserved one for a long time" is more reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Online dictionaries can also be used to look up phrases. The ODO's note for [had it coming](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/come?q=had%20it%20coming#come__60) reads thus:

> have it coming (to one)
>   *informal* be due for retribution on account of something bad that one has done:
>   *his uppity sister-in-law **had it coming** to her*

It's a rather ... [karmic](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/karma?q=karmic#karma__7) expression.