# "Have another think coming" vs. "have another thing coming"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the origin of the phrase “you’ve got another thing/think coming”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24167/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-youve-got-another-thing-think-coming)

If he thinks I'm going out with him, does he have another *think* or *thing* coming?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="another+think+coming"

Comment: This is a prominent [eggcorn](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=120), and even native speakers are confused about it. Use whichever you please.

Comment: This has been discussed here before: [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/68801/which-is-correct-another-think-coming-or-another-thing-coming) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24167/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-youve-got-another-thing-think-coming).

Comment: @J.R.: Why did you not vote to close as a dup of your second link? That way we'd see the title of the earlier question, which makes it crystal clear it's an exact dup.

Answer (score 2):

I've only ever known it as *another think coming*. The OED records *another thing coming*, but as a 'misapprehension'.

Comment: Yes. The eggcorn is in over-correcting *think* into *thing*. *Think* is ungrammatical, but *thing* makes no sense at all.

Comment: You've got to be kiddink! I always thought "another thing" was the correct one and "think" was the eggcorn. Oh well.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: It isn’t ungrammatical. _Think_ has been in colloquial use as a noun with various meanings since 1835. _To have another think coming_ dates from 1898.

Answer (score 0):

*Another think* is probably more correct. This [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=another+thing+coming%2Canother+think+coming&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) shows *another think* predating *another thing*.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_another_think_coming) has a full entry for *another think*, but lists *another thing* as only an [alternative form](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_another_thing_coming)

The confusion (even amongst native speakers) is from the final /k/ of 'think' being unreleased (or palatalised according to some), because the required series of two /k/ sounds is very difficult to articulate. The same thing occurs with 'pink cadillac'.

Comment: In saying *think coming*, the *ng* sound is shorter than in *thing coming*, and there's a gap. At least, it is when I say it. I don't put two /k/s in though. I don't know how to represent that pronunciation in IPA.

Comment: @AndrewLeach [Glottal stop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glottal_stop)

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever heard "another thing coming" - I'm in the US if that makes a difference.  But, I looked it up, and it turns out "think" is actually the correct version, derived from the full expression, "If that's what you think, you've got another think coming."  [This source](http://www.connectingsingles.com/article13/5-sayings-most-people-get-wrong.htm) pretty accurately describes my experience with the phrase - "You've got another thing coming" is much more common, and many people have never heard the correct "another think coming" before.