# How neutral is "then think again"?

Tags: connotation

I am not a native English speaker and in some cases particular phrasing can sound neutral to me but actually be rude and vice versa. I always thought that "think again" in phrases like "If you think that ..., then think again" is something if not rude but at least passive aggressive. But recently I've encountered a lot of examples of "think again" that put my "this-is-rude" hypothesis in question.

For instance:

> If you think the influencer’s penchant for big lips reflects a modern beauty fad, then think again.

or

> But if the song sets you up to expect some kind of concerted attempt at a pop crossover — his John Legend moment, let’s say — then think again.

So, my question is - how much "then think again" is neutral? Can I, for instance, use it in corporate communications?

Comment: It depends how informal you want your corporate communications to be. Both your examples read as though they are from articles written in a light, conversational tone.

Comment: "Corporate communications" can mean anything from ad copy or internal communications about staff parties in a cool tech business or an entertainment venue, to the most formal output from a bank or funeral parlour. A chain of nightclubs does not communicate in the same language as an insurance company.

Comment: @StuartF this is exactly why I'm asking a question whether it's neutral. There are phrases that are valid in 100% cases  - like saying "I disagree" there are phrases that are inappropriate in ANY corporate environment - like you know, "fuck you". And there's a lof of things in the middle.

Comment: @KateBunting so is it informal but not rude?

Comment: In speech, context, intonation, gesture, and facial expression will always make the difference between a friendly (yes, it can sound friendly) and a rude "think again".

Comment: An impersonal appearance of the phrase in an advertisement is not aggressive. In a conversation between two people, it amounts to saying "You are wrong." How neutral is that?

Comment: I am voting to close because it is largely a matter of opinion and context, and because I think the existing comments have covered the ground helpfully and well.

Comment: It's only rude if you say it aggressively in conversation.

Comment: @Anton, the correct answer to this question may indeed be that the rudeness of the phrase is **context**-dependent, but that doesn't make the question itself **opinion**-based in the sense in which this phrase is used on this site. Explaining when a phrase will be perceived as rude, and when it won't be is not a matter of opinion, and is well within the domain of this site. If the comments have already covered the ground well, they can be 'upgraded' to a formal answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you for this comment and I honestly believe it's good and complete enough to be converted to an asnwer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Think again*** is just an established "set phrase" meaning *You are mistaken. I will tell you what you **should** be thinking.*

It's not always an "arrogant" usage. Nobody would be annoyed by an advert saying something like *Thought you couldn't afford a Rolls-Royce? Think again!*

But it's typically used in contexts like *If you think you can pull the wool over my eyes then you can think again* - for example, a teacher or similar "talking down" to his charges. It reminds me of [*You've got another think coming!,*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24167/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-youve-got-another-thing-think-coming) which I'd say is *always* somewhat contemptuous.

I'd certainly advise non-native Anglophones to avoid it unless they're absolutely certain their target audience won't resent having whatever they currently think casually dismissed like that.

Comment: +1 I'd put that caveat in boldface.

Comment: You mean ***unless they're absolutely certain** [it'll be accepted]*?

Answer (score 0):

If you think "think again" is safe for work, think again.

In AmE, "think again" is a form of finger-wagging or confrontation when it's used directly person-to-person rather than in contexts like the Rolls Royce example FumbleFingers gave, where you'd be happy to learn you'd been wrong. I *can* afford one after all!

I can think of very few situations at work where that phrase would go over well, especially in situations where you really want to use it!

> If you think I'm going to work this weekend because you've been dragging your feet hiring a replacement for Bob, think again.
>
> If you think my direct reports  are going to be happy with a 1% raise when I've given them "consistently exceeds expectations" on their quarterly reviews, think again.

I don't think it's used as follows, merely to say that someone is  *wrong* about a fact:

> If you think Messi scored two goals in that game, think again.

but I would agree with FumbleFingers that it's about what the other person *should be thinking*, in the sense that  the phrase is typically used to confront someone about their *attitude and behavior*.

I've been asked to say whether I think the expression is sometimes "arrogant". I suppose it could be arrogant sometimes. But I know that it is probably *imprudent* to use this expression at work, when it is used in the confrontation mode rather than the you-will-be-happy-to-learn-you-are-wrong mode. And that is the case whether it is used with a superior or with a coworker on your own "level" or with a subordinate.

Comment: You should back this up or otherwise give an explanation. I think it is "safe for work" (at least in some contexts) especially compared with language that really isn't and will send you straight to HR, such as slurs.

Comment: @Laurel If you think I'm going to back this up, think again.  Is that backup enough?

Comment: It would be helpful to those who come to this page in the future if you made it more explicit how you disagree with @FumbleFingers. Note that FumbleFingers says that this is 'not **always** an "arrogant" usage' (which implicates that it sometimes is) and advises non-native speakers against using it unless they really know what they are doing.

Comment: @jsw29: I've added a remark to address "arrogance". Perhaps you could ask FumbleFingers for an example of the arrogant usage?

Comment: @jsw29, TimR: Surely *if you think you can pull the wool over my eyes then you can think again* is an example of the "arrogant" usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not if the person is actually trying to pull the wool over my eyes. I would call it "confrontational" but not "arrogant".

Comment: I think that's a relatively meaningless fine distinction in the current context, where all that really matters is whether you could reasonably use the expression when talking to, say, your boss at work. *Hey, boss! You thought I wouldn't finish project X until the end of the year. But think again! I started it the help of chatgpt this morning, and it's already more than halfway complete!* That's "non-confrontational", same as my "Rolls-Royce" example, By comparison, the "pull the wool over my eyes" is definitely aggressive / arrogant / confrontational / ***unwise*** when talking to your boss!